# Getting "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loc'"

Tags: python-3.x

I am calculating the sum of columns using `loc`, but I am getting  the following error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loc'

Pasted below is my code:

```
top_C2_index = sum(sub_sector_df1.loc['C2']['Contribution%'].cumsum(axis=0) < 80)+1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `sub_sector_df1` is being set to `None` somewhere before that line is being run.

Answer (score 2):

Your `sub_sector_df1` hasn't been **instantiated with a value**, i.e. its value is of type `None` by default then. Can you paste how you're instantiating `sub_sector_df1`?

**Note**: I don't have enough privilege to comment..

Hopefully that makes sense!